# How can I use Jquery/JS to change CSS property in Wordpress based on URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a website using WordPress, a theme and slider revolution. I'd like for a hyperlink in the mobile menu to change the font based on the URL. Example, if a user is currently on /about, the css font property is changed using jquery/javascript.

I'd like to know what JS/jquery code to use and how to add into WordPress?

Apologies but I'm new to JS/jquery

Thanks

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: There is probablt already a class in the menu called `current-item` or something like that, which you can just target with css. - but without more info, we can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a menu with a CSS class .menu like this:

```
<ul class='menu'>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

To get the page url your visitor on:

```
let currentURL = window.location.href.split('/').pop(); //Gets the url, splits it by / and return the last piece which is the URL you need.
```

Then save your menu links somewhere:

```
let menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');
```

This is a NodeList so we can use forEach to see which one is the you need:

```
menuLinks.forEach(link => {
  if(link.href.includes(currentURL)) {
    //You can add inline styling like this
    link.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
    link.style.fontWeight = "Bold";
    // Or you can add another class name to the element
    link.classList.add('currentUrlStyle'); // You need to style .currentUrlStyle selector in your css file.
  }
}
```

Based on your question, something like this might solve your solution. It's in Vanilla JS.

Comment: Hi Same, thanks for your suggestion. I've added this code to both the slider revolution JS area which didn't work and then tried to add it to the WordPress theme JS area which also caused the same issue.

Comment: I received the following error. (index):577 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
us.core.min.js?ver=6.8:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollDuration' of undefined
    at new USScroll (us.core.min.js?ver=6.8:35)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (us.core.min.js?ver=6.8:71)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)

Comment: This could be a conflict with the WP plugin slider revolution?

Comment: I have no idea. Also the code I suggested wouldn’t work unless you adjust it to your code.